# Add control by code in CBasePropertyPage Dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, directshow

I'm writing my first Direct show filter, and everything works fine except when I try to create the custom properties page for the filter.

I would like to create one checkbox control foreach output pin available in the filter.

```
HRESULT CActivateDeliveryProp::OnActivate(void)
{

  ... 

  CWnd * pMyWindow;
  pMyWindow = CWnd::FromHandle(this->m_hwnd); // or may (this->m_Dlg); ??

   ...

  CButton *chkOutputPin;
  chkOutputPin = new CButton;
  chkOutputPin->Create(_T("&my check")
     , WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |   BS_AUTOCHECKBOX
     , CRect(10, iTopPosition, 140, 35),pMyWindow, 0x11);

}
```

- Is this the correct way to get the handle to the parent dialog?

**Update:**

Sorry, I didn't express my real problem well, I only wrote a part of my problem. I don't have problem getting main parent form.
My problem is when I try to add a new CheckBox control I get this assertion and code doesn't work.
[image: Assertion]

Thanks for all!

Comment: DirectShow DLLs are typically non-MFC projects, where `CWnd::FromHandle` is not applicable. It does not mean you cannot use MFC there, it is not just as easy as simply to start using MFC classes. You typically use plain Win API.

Comment: I'm using MFC libraries. I think I don't have problem with it

Comment: Well, you should have no problem accessing `CBasePropertyPage::m_hwnd` then, just as you shown in your question. `m_Dlg` is a copy of the handle and is never used across BaseClasses.

Comment: Ok, and how can I add control to my CWnd object? (Sorry I'm newbie in this :S)

Comment: Hit the second button and check position in MFC source. It's apparently MFC related problem of doing stuff in a non-MFC window. You said you don't have problems with MFC library. Apparently you do.